# Count time values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a document that I've imported with `pandas` in Python. There are time values in the column, and I want to find out how many values there are from hour 8 - 10 and from 10-12. I'm not sure where to start. I've tried `(data.loc[(data['Time'] >= 8 & (data['Time'] < 10)]` , but I'm getting invalid syntax. How do I do this?

```
TIME
08:04:16
08:04:53
...
10:04:05
...
08:59:21
...
15:56:10
```

Full data looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/avqWi.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your column is of *object* type (actually it holds *string*s).

So the first step is to convert it to *datetime* type (the date part
is taken from the current day, but this doesn't matter).

Then you should read the hour (*dt.hour*) from it and check whether
it is in the desired range, e.g. using *between* (the result is for now
a *bool* Series).

And the only remaining step to do is to *sum* it (counting *True* values).

So the code to check for hour between *8* and *10* can be:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Time).dt.hour.between(8,10).sum()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I think it worked when I used `pd.to_datetime(df.Time).dt.hour.between(8, 9.9).sum())
` At least I got the correct answer (98).

Answer (score 4):

Convert to timedelta

```
df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)

m = (df.Time>='08:00:00') & (df.Time<'10:00:00')

df1 = df[m].copy()
```